# calculating the average length of split vector

Tags: r, pseudocode

Consider the following vector (or dataframe or datatable)

```
a = data.frame(x = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1))
```

`x` represents a 'state', either 1 or 2. The vector data represents spatial data and I am looking to get the average length per state. In other words, we see, for fixed `state = 2` there are two segments: `2, 2, 2, 2` and `2, 2, 2` with lengths `4` and `3`. Thus the 'avg' length of this state is `(4 + 3)/2 = 3.5`.

My actual dataset has states from 1- 9 and has over 1,000,000 points in the vector. My difficulty is really 'breaking' up the vector and counting the segments. I am working with R but pseudocode would be fine.

Note: if anyone can come up with a better title, please let me know or submit an edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve this with a combination of `?rle` and `?tapply`.
`rle` counts the number of consecutive elements and stores them in `lengths` and the corresponding values in `values`. `tapply` is used to calculate the groupwise `mean`:

```
r <- rle(a$x)
tapply(r$lengths, INDEX=r$values, FUN=mean)
#   1   2 
# 3.5 3.5
```

Comment: Wow simple answer! Didn't know about the `rle` function.